# Strange format of interval value returned by PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, intervals

I have PostgreSQL 9.5.0 and I observe strange interval values returned by very similar queries. I thought that then interval is bigger than 24 hours then it is returned with `days` part like this:

```
SELECT (1000 * ('2016-02-04 12:00:11'::timestamp - '2016-02-03 12:00:00'::timestamp)::interval)::interval

1000 days 03:03:20
```

But sometimes hours are not converted to days:

```
SELECT (1000 * ('2016-02-04 11:00:11'::timestamp - '2016-02-03 12:00:00'::timestamp)::interval)::interval

23003:03:20
```

How can I force the same output format with days part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`justify_hours()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT justify_hours(1000 * ('2016-02-04 11:00:11'::timestamp - '2016-02-03 12:00:00'))

   justify_hours   
-------------------
 958 days 11:03:20
(1 row)
```

or `justify_interval()`:

```
SELECT justify_interval(1000 * ('2016-02-04 11:00:11'::timestamp - '2016-02-03 12:00:00'))

        justify_interval         
---------------------------------
 2 years 7 mons 28 days 11:03:20
(1 row)
```

See also: [Why postgres show two different format for same interval value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111382/1995738)