# Why postgres show two different format for same interval value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.5

I was helping with this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080314/difference-between-two-dates-postgresql-in-excel-format/38081079#38081079)** trying to change the format for the interval.

```
from '01 day 22:10:37'  to  '46:10:37'
```

I give a solution with string manipulation. But then I found postgres can show the same interval on two different format.

```
SELECT '2016-01-27 08:51:02'::timestamp - '2016-01-25 10:40:25'::timestamp end_date,
       '46:10:37'::interval interval_date;
```

Funny thing. There is a **[function](http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/justify_hours-function.php)** doing the inverse process

```
 justify_hours('46:10:37'::interval) --> '1 day 22:10:37'
```

So I wondering if there is a direct way to solve this problem. And why same interval value has two different result.

### pgAdmin output:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an interval is **a difference between two timestamps** it is always justified to hours (i.e. it has *standard* format). Examples:

```
select
    '2015-01-01 13:0:0'::timestamp - '2014-01-01 23:0:0'::timestamp, --> 364 days 14:00:00
    '2015-01-01 13:0:0'::timestamp - '2014-01-01 03:0:0'::timestamp, --> 365 days 10:00:00
    '2015-01-01 13:0:0'::timestamp - '2015-01-01 03:0:0'::timestamp; --> 10:00:00
```

**Calculations on intervals** are executed on date part and time part separately, so they may lead to strange formats. Examples:

```
select 
    '2 day 1:00:00'::interval- '1 day 2:00:00'::interval,    --> 1 day -01:00:00 (!!)
    '2 day 100:00:00'::interval+ '1 day 60:00:00'::interval, --> 3 days 160:00:00
    '2 day 100:00:00'::interval- '2 day 60:00:00'::interval; --> 40:00:00
```

For such cases Postgres developers provided the appropriate function for the *format standardization*:

```
select 
    justify_hours('1 day -01:00:00'),  --> 23:00:00
    justify_hours('3 days 160:00:00'), --> 9 days 16:00:00
    justify_hours('40:00:00');         --> 1 day 16:00:00
```

However they did not think that the reverse operation would be needful. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082414/1995738) I proposed a function to convert a date part of an interval to hours. I think it can be (with some minor changes) some kind of *reverse function* for `justify_hours()`:

```
create or replace function unjustify_hours(interval)
returns interval language sql as $$
    select format('%s:%s',
        (extract (epoch from $1) / 3600)::int,
        to_char($1, 'mi:ss'))::interval;
$$;

select 
    unjustify_hours('23:00:00'),        --> 23:00:00
    unjustify_hours('9 days 16:00:00'), --> 232:00:00
    unjustify_hours('1 day 16:00:00');  --> 40:00:00
```

The function `to_char(interval, text)` cannot be helpful here, as

```
select 
    to_char(interval '23:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'),        --> 23:00:00
    to_char(interval '9 days 16:00:00', 'hh24:mi:ss'), --> 16:00:00 (!)
    to_char(interval '1 day 16:00:00',  'hh24:mi:ss'); --> 16:00:00 (!)
```

Note that an interval can be correctly formatted in many ways:

```
select 
    justify_hours('100:00:00'),        --> 4 days 04:00:00
    justify_hours('1 days 76:00:00'),  --> 4 days 04:00:00
    justify_hours('2 days 52:00:00'),  --> 4 days 04:00:00
    justify_hours('5 days -20:00:00'); --> 4 days 04:00:00
```

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html):

> According to the SQL standard all fields of an interval value must
>   have the same sign, so a leading negative sign applies to all fields;
>   for example the negative sign in the interval literal '-1 2:03:04'
>   applies to both the days and hour/minute/second parts. PostgreSQL
>   allows the fields to have different signs, and traditionally treats
>   each field in the textual representation as independently signed, so
>   that the hour/minute/second part is considered positive in this
>   example. If IntervalStyle is set to sql_standard then a leading sign
>   is considered to apply to all fields (but only if no additional signs
>   appear). Otherwise the traditional PostgreSQL interpretation is used.
>   To avoid ambiguity, it's recommended to attach an explicit sign to
>   each field if any field is negative.

and

> Internally interval values are stored as months, days, and seconds.
>   This is done because the number of days in a month varies, and a day
>   can have 23 or 25 hours if a daylight savings time adjustment is
>   involved. The months and days fields are integers while the seconds
>   field can store fractions. Because intervals are usually created from
>   constant strings or timestamp subtraction, this storage method works
>   well in most cases. Functions justify_days and justify_hours are
>   available for adjusting days and hours that overflow their normal
>   ranges.

Comment: Hello, I'm here from the future, and your function is exactly what I needed! However I'm not sure about this part: "(with some minor changes)" what exactly is wrong with your function?

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean that the function should be improved. I just changed the function's result type from `text` to `interval` (comparing this function to that of the quoted answer).

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html

> `to_char(interval)` formats `HH` and `HH12` as shown on a 12-hour clock,
>   i.e. zero hours and 36 hours output as 12, while `HH24` outputs the full
>   hour value, which can exceed 23 for intervals.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html

> `to_char(interval)` formats `HH` and `HH12` as hours in a single day, while
>   `HH24` can output hours exceeding a single day, e.g. >24.

I'd guess that the first one use implicit format based on the result of the subtraction, and the second use an explicit format based on the input.

Comment: But if you check pgAdmin output, result is an `interval` not a `string`. And `HH12` mean 12am/pm  so range from `00-12` but HH24 mean `00-23`

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the answer [klin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1995738/klin) provided is not correct as casting to int rounds the number. If it rounds up, you get +1 extra hour to the returning value. The correct way is to truncate it. Here is my version:

```
create or replace function unjustify_hours(interval)
    returns interval language sql as $$
select format('%s:%s',
              trunc(extract (epoch from $1) / 3600),
              to_char($1, 'mi:ss'))::interval;
$$;
```

P.S. I can't leave comments under answers as I'm a new user and don't have enough reputation yet.